# "Cannot create extension" in Eclipse (Android)

Tags: android, eclipse

I recently started using eclipse to compile my Android code (which I'm also pretty new at) and I tried to download another eclipse.exe that was supposed to be for C++. Anyways, I don't know if that would be the cause of my problems but I noticed that after I tried to give myself the option of compiling C++, just the main file in my Android project gave me the error "cannot create extension." Anyone know how I can fix this? Again, it's just in the one file so i wouldn't think it's a setting issue but I'm not really sure.

This is what my window looks like

[image]

TIA

Comment: Can you show the code of your `MainActivity` at which line you are getting error ? Have you tried cleaning your project ?

Comment: I've tried cleaning to no avail. And i can't view the code because when i click on the file tab, all I get is what you see in the photo above.

Comment: Just close the eclipse once and try to open again.

Comment: still looks like the picture above, after closing and reopening

Comment: Make sure you have properly installed your ADT plugins and provided the android SDK also.

Comment: they should be. I had no problem running android code before. I don't see why they would have gotten uninstalled. how would i check?

Comment: it seems as though the extension error is in regard to git? I have git and github on my computer but i dont remember do anything to associate it with eclipse..

Comment: Is your result same for the another java file also ? Its also not showing the code even ?

Comment: no. for the other file (but in the same project) it displays the code just fine. it's only in the main file that it is having problems

Comment: Have you tried to convert the java file into C++ file code ?

Comment: no. im writing code for android. isn't that java?